# How to convert imageview to bytearray in kotlin

Tags: android, imageview, kotlin

How to convert imageview to bytearray kotlin android

In java

```
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)image.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
ByteArrayOutputStream stream=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, stream);
byte[] image=stream.toByteArray();

return image
```

Comment: You can copy paste this code in your Kotlin file in Android Studio and it will get converted to Kotlin.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Here it is use java to kotlin converter.

```
val bitmap = (image.getDrawable() as BitmapDrawable).getBitmap()
val stream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, stream)
val image = stream.toByteArray()
```

Comment: Note: AFAIK PNG is lossless and quality parameter has no effect

Answer (score 3):

This may help you,

```
private fun imageToBitmap(image: ImageView): ByteArray {
    val bitmap = (image.drawable as BitmapDrawable).bitmap
    val stream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, stream)

    return stream.toByteArray()
}
```